# Make to annotation callout link to a new view on mkmapkit

Tags: xcode, annotations

Xcode:
I got the below annotation code form GitHub
https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation

When I click on the annotation, nothing happens. I want users to be brought to a new view which will display text and an image of the location on which the pin is placed.

I presume I have to create a new viewcontroller but how do I link each annotation to its own view?

I take it I create a new viewcontrol and somehow name(or tag) it? If so what is the code to link the callout to that unique "named" view controller?

Apparently this is a common question but I have received no guidance on this nor are there quality videos online to show how this is done.

Anyone help?

Comment: Any insightful answers?